# Flutter progresscolor in linearpercentindicator

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show results (as below);

```
void initState() {
    if (finalD < 10) {
      message = "Normal :  $finalD";
      //progress = Colors.green as double;
    } else if (finalD < 14) {
      message = "Mild : $finalD";
    } else if (finalD < 21) {
      message = "Moderate : $finalD";
    } else if (finalD < 28) {
      message = "Severe : $finalD";
    } else {
      message = "Extremely Severe : $finalD";
      //progress = Colors.red as double;
    }
  }
```

by showing the linear percent indicator;

```
LinearPercentIndicator(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                  animation: true,
                  lineHeight: 25.0,
                  animationDuration: 2500,
                  percent: percentage,
                  center: Text(message),
                  linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                  progressColor: Colors.yellow,
                ),
```

How can I make the **progressColor** changes depends on the if-else conditions?

Comment: Create a Color variable and update it accordingly

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Okay. i wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Color variable `Color progressColor = Colors.yellow` then update it accordingly like this

```dart
void initState() {
    if (finalD < 10) {
      message = "Normal :  $finalD";
      //progress = Colors.green as double;
      progressColor = Colors.green;
    } else if (finalD < 14) {
      message = "Mild : $finalD";
      progressColor = Colors.red;
    } else if (finalD < 21) {
      message = "Moderate : $finalD";
      progressColor = Colors.pink;
    } else if (finalD < 28) {
      message = "Severe : $finalD";
      progressColor = Colors.purple;
    } else {
      message = "Extremely Severe : $finalD";
      //progress = Colors.red as double;
      progressColor = Colors.red;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

then add the Color to your widget

```dart
LinearPercentIndicator(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                  animation: true,
                  lineHeight: 25.0,
                  animationDuration: 2500,
                  percent: percentage,
                  center: Text(message),
                  linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
                  progressColor: progressColor,
                ),
```